# C#, winforms, datatable, button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview bound to a datatable. One of the columns in the Datasource is a BLOB. Its a BLOB in the database and I am retrieving all the records from the DB to the Datatable, then binding it to the DGV.

here's a check I am to make. For the Blob columns(Documents pdfs,docs rpt txt), if there is a value other than DBNull then a button should be disabled. If other than DBNull, a buttton should be highlighted and available to download

1) How would I add a button to this DGV which is being bound to a Datatable. 
2) Where and in which event should I check the value of BLOb field

Thank you
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your button click you will need to use this code:

```
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
     saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";

     Byte[] blob = null;
     FileStream fs = null;
     blob = new Byte[(dr.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
     dr.GetBytes[0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);

     saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
     fs = (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
     fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
     fs.Close();
```

This will be the code to enable or disable the button

```
 if (dt[columnname] != dbnull.value)
 {
   button.enabled = true;

 }
 else
 {
   button.enabled = false;
 }
```

Comment: What is sdr. Also, it is possible to add an additional button column to a datagridview which is being populated by a datatable. This button should be able to retrieve docs, add documents. For retrieving docs, do u have any sample code. PS: My DGV's datasource is a datatable.

Comment: Did you get this to work ? I have done some more thinking about it I think its wrong

Comment: I am having trouble with button.enabled. is this  DataGridViewButtonCell button = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells["ButtonColumnName"].Value; If it is then there is no button.enabled. Microsoft has some example related http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx. Also, How would I get to display the name of the document uploaded by the user as the text for this button cell

Comment: Your going to want to store the name of the file in a different field in the database cause it is a blob there is no way to store that in the same field then that can be the text for your button

Comment: Also, does the example answer you question ?

Comment: @ Micah Armantrout: Yes it does very well. Except for the button. Is it a Button or a DataGridViewButtonColumn